# How to pass View Model value as parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

So i have this Navigation file (Navigation.kt)

```
@Composable
fun AppNavigation() {
    val navController : NavHostController = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
            val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
            NavigationBar(
                containerColor = White,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(60.dp)
                    .drawBehind {
                        val strokeWidth = 1f
                        val x = size.width - strokeWidth

                        //top line navbar
                        drawLine(
                            color = Gray,
                            start = Offset(0f, 0f), //(0,0) at top-left point of the box
                            end = Offset(x, 0f), //top-right point of the box
                            strokeWidth = strokeWidth
                        )
                    }
            ){
                listOfNavItems.forEach { navItem ->
                    NavigationBarItem(
                        colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(
                            selectedIconColor = Color(0xFF2493DC),
                            unselectedIconColor = Gray,
                            indicatorColor = Color(0xFFEEEEEE)
                        ),
                        selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == navItem.route } == true,
                        onClick = {
                            navController.navigate(navItem.route){
                                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id){
                                    saveState = true
                                }
                                launchSingleTop = true
                                restoreState = true
                            }
                        },
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = navItem.icon ,
                                contentDescription = null)
                        },
//                        label = {
//                            Text(text = navItem.label)
//                        }

                    )

                }
            }
        }
    ){
        paddingValues ->
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Screens.HomePageScreen.name,
            modifier = Modifier.
                padding(paddingValues)
        ){
            composable(route = Screens.HomePageScreen.name){
                HomePageShow(navController = navController)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Main Screen file (HomePage.kt)

```
class HomePage : ComponentActivity() {

    private val viewModel by viewModels<ProductsViewModel>(factoryProducer = {
        object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return ProductsViewModel(ProductRepositoryImpl(RetrofitInstance.api))
                        as T
            }
        }
    })

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ITJobstreetTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {

                    val productList = viewModel.products.collectAsState().value
                    val context = LocalContext.current
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    LaunchedEffect(key1 = viewModel.showErrorToastChannel) {
                        viewModel.showErrorToastChannel.collectLatest { show ->
                            if (show) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                ).show()
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (productList.isEmpty()) {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                        ) {
                            CircularProgressIndicator()
                        }
                    } else {
                        LazyColumn(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                            contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)
                        ) {
                            items(productList.size) { index ->
                                HomePageShow(navController, productList[index])
                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun HomePageShow(navController: NavController, product: Product) {
    Scaffold()
```

So calling HomePageShow() in my navigation files gives me error since it requires two parameters which is navController and Product. But i don't know how to pass the product since its in two different files, im trying to pass the value from API to Main Screen.

This is my very first kotlin / programming project, i value any guidance offered

Answer (score 0):

You Did it in bad way, your HomePage should be a @Composable function, not and Activity. first of create HomePage Composable function like this:

```
@Composable
fun HomePage(naveGraph: NavHostController, viewModel: ProductsViewModel) 
{
  // your codes
}
```

you should put your AppNavigation() inside Activity.